# Can columname be variable in mysql update syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I want to update whatever column value in table. If I echo $q it gets  the variables but it won't update and won't echo mysql error. So how can I do it?

```
 function up($name, $value, $id){     

 $q='UPDATE Table SET '.$name.'='.$value.' WHERE ID="'.$id.'"';
     $r=mysql_query($q, $conn);
     if(!$r){
     echo('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
   } else{ echo "Updated data successfully\n"; } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$q` is interpreted before being sent to MySQL so you can have the column names, and everything else for that matter, be dynamic at runtime. The final value of that string is what MySQL will see.

If you're row is not updating and you're not getting an error then your query is incorrect in some manner. Make sure all of your conditions in your WHERE clause are correct. And a better way to see if your rows were affected is to use [`mysql_affected_rows()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

```
else{ echo "Updated data successfully\n"; }
```

should be

```
else if(mysql_affected_rows() !== 0){ echo "Updated data successfully\n"; }
```

FYI, you should consider migrating away from mysql_* functions since [they will soon be going away.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/3656047#3656047)

Comment: Turned out I had to connect to the database again inside the function. Actually I already had this solution but somehow deleted it.  But thank you for the FYI!